# Problemas con span

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un span editable pero cuando digito caracteres o numero me dice que esta vacio que puedo hacer

```js
  alert($('#ClienteId').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputs">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="ClienteId" contenteditable="true" style="background: rgb(255,255,255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%" tabindex="10">Span Editable</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: podrias explicarte mejor lo que deseas hacer, de hecho si solo agregas el atributo contentEditable al span funciona sin problemas y sin jquery o javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( () => {

  $(document).on('keyup', '#ClienteId', function() {

    console.log( $(this).text() );

  });


});
```

```css
#ClienteId {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputs">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="ClienteId" contenteditable="true" tabindex="10">Cambia el texto</span>
</div>
```

la etiquetas `span, p, label, i` etc. No tienen un atributo por default de tipo value, como in `input` por ejemplo pero tienen un text, con Jquery sería `.text()` Te dejo un ejemplo con el listener `keyup`

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien que deseas hacer, pero podrías intentar algo como esto:

```
let span = document.querySelector('#ClienteId');

function getText(e)
{
  console.log(this.textContent);
}

span.addEventListener('keyup', getText)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Al ejecutar tu código me tira un error:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 15,
  "colno": 9
}
```

Que no reconozca el signo $ me da a entender que no estás importando JQuery como librería en tu página.

De cualquier manera no es necesario usar JQuery. Tal y como muestra Diego Avila y Isaac Cantún se puede usar JavaScript para obtener el valor que buscás de muchas maneras, por ejemplo:

```
alert(document.getElementById('ClienteId').innerHTML);
```

En cualquier caso, podrías dar un poco más de contexto?

Comment: el mensaje de error lo tira porque no agrego la libreria jQuery en el editor de la pagina

Comment: Algún comentario sobre tu código?